# Show $\int_X f d\nu = \int_X fgd\mu$ if $\nu(E)=\int_E g d\mu$ .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$f$ and $g$ are both non-negative functions where the integral of non-negative function is defined as the supremum over all simple functions dominated by the non-negative function.

Would going through the definition of supremum work?

This is an exercise in Royden. He gives this hint:  Establish it for simple functions, use Simple approximation Lemma and Monotone Convergence theorem.

Comment: Yes, going through the definition should work. @E.Costa's hint also works.

Comment: You might also use, in conjunction with the definition, one of the convergence theorems.

Comment: I recommend that you follow the hint. It pretty much gives the solution. Did you try and get stuck somewhere? If you want to use the definition of the supremum, I suspect you'll end up proving results similar to those in the hint anyway.

Comment: Yeah I did it already thanks.

Comment: Over the years I've learned that if you want to prove anything involving integrals the best place to start is by showing the property holds for characteristic functions then showing simple then using the fact that measurable functions can be approximated by simple functions to finish the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f=\chi_E$, then conjunction is obvious. Using linearity of the Lebesgue integral we conclude conjunction for simple positive function. If $f$ is positive measurable, then we can find sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ positive simple functions such that $s_n \uparrow f$, then $s_n g \uparrow fg$, and then we can apply Monotone Convergence theorem to find $$\int_X f \,d\nu=\int_X \lim_{n\to \infty} s_n\, d\nu =\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X  s_n \,d\nu =\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X  s_n g\, d\mu= \int_X  f g \,d\mu$$

Also, I think we need assumption that $g \in L^1 (\mu),$ but I suppose we say that when we say $\nu (E)=\int_E g d\mu$, or $d\nu = g d\mu$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Use the uniquiness of Radon-Nikodym derivative in [Radon-Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). 
Define $m(\,E\,)=\int_{E}f\, d\nu$. Then $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative (unique in $L^1(X)$) of $m$ with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: You could do that, but the result follows from basic definitions and the monotone convergence theorem. No need for such a strong theorem.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, Either way is an answer. And the questioner has not demanded that used some convergence theorem. But I will consider your comment.

Comment: Just pointing that out in case the OP wasn't familiar with Radon-Nikodym. Also, the proof I'm familiar with for Radon-Nikodym actually uses the result in the question.

Comment: Yes, using R-N for this is a bit strange, for the reason @AymanHourieh explained.